# Grouping sequelize data in separate objects

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i am new with nodejs express with posgresql , i made a route like this :

```
  get: async (req, res, next) => {
       
        var cat = await sequelize.query(
            `
            SELECT 
o."id" as "cart_id", 
o."user_id", 
o."createdBy",
o."createdAt", 
o."updatedAt",
i."quantity",
pi."name",
pi."price"
FROM "Orders" AS o
Left join public."CartItem" i on  i."cart_id"=o."id"
Left join public."Item" pi on  pi."id"=i."product_id"
WHERE o."user_id"=${req.body.user_id}

            `
            ,
         { type: QueryTypes.SELECT,group:`i."cart_id"` })
            .catch(e => res.send(e))
        if (cat) {
            // console.log(cat.Orders)
            cat.map(e=> {
                console.log(e)
            })
            res.send(cat)
        }
    },
```

if i hit this route with postman i get this response :

```
[
    {
        "cart_id": 9,
        "user_id": 1,
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "quantity": 4,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": 12000
    },
    {
        "cart_id": 9,
        "user_id": 1,
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "quantity": 4,
        "name": "test2",
        "price": 12000
    }
]
```

My question is, is it possible to assemble the response in the following way:

```
[
    "cart_9":[
    {
     
        "user_id": 1,
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "quantity": 4,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": 12000
    },
    {
     
        "user_id": 1,
        "createdBy": null,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-11T09:51:47.968Z",
        "quantity": 4,
        "name": "test2",
        "price": 12000
    }
]
]
```

- note that the response assembled by the "cart_id" .

any suggestion to assemble the response and get the required response ?

Comment: Sequelize can group results only if you use models and associations between them

Comment: @Anatoly what if i want to use only raw query?

Comment: Then you can have only a nested objects (not array) if you use `nest` option and you dots in column names

Comment: @Anatoly how to group if we has association ?

Comment: indicate aliases with as many dots as you have nested associations.